# Drag and drop scaleable content offset()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, offset

I have 4 puzzle pieces on left side and another 4 on right side. I need to drag the pieces from right side to the left side and make them join...The problem is that, my content is scaleable so if I drop a piece onto dropspot, when I resize the page it will remain there and wont be fitted with the left side puzzle piece. I have read something about offset,shall help in this case?

Here's what i have tried with divs as drop spot but i can't make pieces fit in drop spots when im over them and if I resize page, pieces aren't joined:

http://jsfiddle.net/zf66b/7/

Code:

```
$(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < piesedrag.length; i++)
    {
    $(piesedrag[i]).draggable
    ({
        containment: "#decor",
        cursor: "move",
        revert: "invalid",
        });
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < dropspot.length; i++)
    {
          $( dropspot[i] ).droppable({  
            /*  tolerance: "intersect",*/

          drop: function( event, ui ) 
            {
            tolerance: 'intersect'
            }    
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Hey, Romanian brother! :-)

Comment: Hello to you too! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

To make it work correctly you have to change size and position from percents to fixed values, here are few fixes:

```
right {
  left:400px;
  width:200px 
}
.left {
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}
#dropspot3 {
/* margin-left: 34%; */
width: 150px;
}
```

Set for every dropspot fixed width and remove percent margin.

Comment: Thanks,but i cant do that. It should be resizable. Main problem is how do i scale the drop zone as part of the left piece